# Why use order by clause will save my sending data time?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, where-clause

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `complete_time` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
;
```

most rows are set `complete_time` to 0

---

when i want to find one row which `complete_time` is 0,i find that if i just use where:

```
desc select * from db.example WHERE complete_time = 0 limit 1;

id          select_type         table           type            possible_keys           key         key_len         ref         rows            Extra
1           SIMPLE          example         ALL         \N          \N          \N          \N          7441194         Using where

Status          Duration
starting            0.000097
checking permissions            0.000086
Opening tables          0.000102
System lock         0.000099
init            0.000090
optimizing          0.000133
statistics          0.000111
preparing           0.000142
executing           0.000131
Sending data            0.070008
end         0.000320
query end           0.000107
closing tables          0.000099
freeing items           0.000143
logging slow query          0.000097
cleaning up         0.000157
```

if i add a `order by` clause,it will hit the `index`:

```
desc select * from db.example WHERE complete_time = 0 order by id limit 1;

id          select_type         table           type            possible_keys           key         key_len         ref         rows            Extra
1           SIMPLE          example         index           \N          PRIMARY         4           \N          1           Using where

Status          Duration
starting            0.000115
checking permissions            0.000092
Opening tables          0.000093
System lock         0.000092
init            0.000096
optimizing          0.000090
statistics          0.000091
preparing           0.000109
executing           0.000086
Sorting result          0.000100
Sending data            0.000128
end         0.000101
query end           0.000088
closing tables          0.000091
freeing items           0.000146
logging slow query          0.000088
cleaning up         0.000092
```

why just a `order by` clause will get so huge differences in performance?

it seem that the first sql take a long time in `sending data`

Are there anyone have any ideas of this?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorting takes time.  Why is that surprising?

Comment: I would guess (but I'm not familiar with mysql), that by using the `order by` you are searching for a specific record (`limit 1`) which can be found. If you omit the `order by` you are looking for an arbitrary record, which may cause all records to be retrieved first.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099620/mysql-taking-forever-sending-data-simple-query-lots-of-data I'm not a MySQL expert, but I do see that under ["type"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#explain_type) the first query has "ALL" whereas the second has "index." It may be that the second query is fetching more data from the index (i.e. memory) rather than disk.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for comment,i want to know what difference of the sorting make two sql such huge differences in performance? is that any hint about this? THX.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Thanks for comment,but i force to use primary index it make no improve of it ```select * from db.example USE INDEX (PRIMARY) WHERE complete_time = 0 limit 1;```